# canvas undefined innerWidth/Height how do i fix this?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

So i am working on the animated background but it dasn't show up.
I dont get any errors in the browser but on the code checking site's it said that i got undefined variables innerWidth and innerHeight, then i tryed few thinks to fix that like

```
let innerWidth = window.innerWidth;
let innerHeight = window.innerHeight;
```

in place of

```
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
```

but it's dasn't work and I came to the point that i do not know what i can do.
I am a noobie in programming world so i hope that you guys can help me out.

This is Javascript code

```js
/*jshint esversion: 6 */

const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas1");
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

let particlesArray;

let mouse = {
  x: null,
  y: null,
  radius: (canvas.height/80) * (canvas.width/80)
};

window.addEventListener('mousemove',
  function(event) {
    mouse.x = event.x;
    mouse.y = event.y;
  }
);

class Particle {
  constructor(x, y, directionX, directionY, size, color) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.directionX = directionX;
    this.directionY = directionY;
    this.size = size;
    this.color = color;
  }

  draw() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.size, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
    ctx.fillStyle = '#8C5523';
    ctx.fill();
  }

  update() {
    if (this.x > canvas.width || this.x < 0) {
      this.directionX = -this.directionX;
    }
    if (this.y > canvas.height || this.y < 0) {
      this.directionY = -this.directionY;
    }

    let dx = mouse.x - this.x;
    let dy = mouse.y - this.y;
    let distance = Math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy);
    if (distance < mouse.radius + this.size) {
      if (mouse.x < this.x && this.x < canvas.width - this.size * 10) {
        this.x += 10;
      }
      if (mouse.x > this.x && this.x > this.size * 10) {
        this.x -= 10;
      }
      if (mouse.y < this.y && this.y < canvas.height - this.size * 10) {
        this.y += 10;
      }
      if (mouse.y > this.y && this.y > this.size * 10) {
        this.y -= 10;
      }
    }
    this.x += this.directionX;
    this.y += this.directionY;
    this.draw();
  }
}

function init() {
  particlesArray = [];
  let numberOfParticles = (canvas.height * canvas.width) / 9000;
  for (let i = 0; i < numberOfParticles; i++) {
    let size = (Math.random() * 5) + 1;
    let x = (Math.random() * ((innerWidth - size * 2) - (size * 2)) + size * 2);
    let y = (Math.random() * ((innerHeight - size * 2) - (size * 2)) + size * 2);
    let directionX = (Math.random() * 5) - 2.5;
    let directionY = (Math.random() * 5) - 2.5;
    let color = '#8C5523';

    particlesArray.push(new Particle(x, y, directionX, directionY, size, color));
  }
}

function connect(){
let opacityValue = 1; 
  for (let a = 0; a < particlesArray.lenght; a++) {
    for (let b = a; b < particlesArray.lenght; b++) {
      let distance = ((particlesArray[a].x - particlesArray[b].x) * (particlesArray[a].x - particlesArray[b].x)) +
        ((particlesArray[a].y - particlesArray[b].y) * (particlesArray[a].y - particlesArray[b].y));
      if (distance < (canvas.width/7) * (canvas.height/7)) {
        opacityValue = 1 - (distance/20000);
        ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgba (140,85,31,' + opacityValue + ')';
        ctx.lineWidth = 1;
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(particlesArray[a].x, particlesArray[a].y);
        ctx.lineTo(particlesArray[b].x, particlesArray[b].y);
        ctx.stroke();
      } 
    }
  }
}

function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, innerWidth, innerHeight);
  
    for (let i = 0; i < particlesArray.lenght; i++) {
      particlesArray[i].update();
    }
    connect();
  }

  window.addEventListener('resize',
  function(){
    canvas.width = innerWidth;
    canvas.height = innerHeight;
    mouse.radius = ((canvas.height/80) * (canvas.height/80));
    init();
  }
);

window.addEventListener('mouseout',
  function(){ 
  mouse.x = undefined;
  mouse.x = undefined;
}
);

init();
animate();
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#canvas1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: radial-gradient(white, lightgrey);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="nl">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-epuiv="X-UA-Compatible" contect="ie=edge">
  <title>Background</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="background.css">
</head>

<body>
  <canvas id="canvas1"></canvas>
  <script src="background.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

MUCH LOVE AND RESPECT FOR HELPING ME OUT AND YOUR TIME

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the height through this (I guess you forgot ctx)

```
ctx.canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
ctx.canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me out unfortunately it still dasn´t work and i get this same error in code checker :/

Comment: @MrNice Does it work with a fixed height and width?

Comment: if i understood it corectly it dasn't work